# Change post-name when inserting new Post if Specific Category is selected in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hook a function for first time when new post is being inserted in WP.

when Poetry category is selected I want to change **post-name** with random 7 numeric numbers like

**/poetry/2837410/**

which function should I call that triger only once when new post is posting

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post',  'my_custom_first_time');

function my_custom_first_time($post_ID, $post, $update){
  //Do your logic here
}
```

The hook `'wp_insert_post'` action fires once a post has been saved. You have the ability to set it to only fire on new posts or on all save actions using the `$update` parameters, by setting it to false.

The downside is that `$update` will be true in a first-time post published if you are using the dashboard because it creates revisions.

Using the `'transition_post_status'` hook allows us to do stuff when a post status changes. In order for the hook to fire the first time when a post is published only, I have added actional logic to check the post status

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_custom_first_time', 10, 3 );

function my_custom_first_time( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

     // check if the post was not previously published and if the new status
    // is equal to publish

    if (  'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ){
            // do your logic here
     }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to change post-name if specific category is selected how to change post-name (slug) in transition_post_status